# problem in uploading .JPG file with laravel Image package

Tags: php, laravel, image

I try to resize and upload an image with Laravel8 Image Package by this blow code:

```
public function addImage($input_image,$folder_name)
    {
$img = Image::make($input_image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(200, 200, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save('thumbs/img-' . verta()->format('h-i-s') .'.'. $input_image->getClientOriginalExtension());

            $image_temp_uploadName = 'img-' . verta()->format('h-i-s') .'.'. $input_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $input_image->move($folder_path, $image_temp_uploadName);

            DB::table('image_tb')->insert([
                'image_name' => $folder_name.'/'.$image_temp_uploadName
            ]);
}
```

It works and everything is ok BUT when I choose a .JPG file (notice than it's different from .jpg) it doesn't work and get this error:

```
{message: "Image source not readable", exception: "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException",…}
exception: "Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotReadableException"
file: "H:\\New_cargo\\Cargo\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\AbstractDecoder.php"
line: 346
message: "Image source not readable"
```